# After migrate to Android Studio 3.0 drawable 'png' NOT compressed in debug build

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, aapt

Drawables compressed in release build types, but NOT compressed in debug build types.

`Android Studio 3.0
Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 20, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.10.0-38-generic`

In previous version drawable was always compressed

How can I configure debug builds to compress `png` drawables also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html)

Here is the quote

> If you're using Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher, PNG crunching is
>   disabled by default for only the "debug" build type

I solved my problem by adding `crunchPngs true` to debug build type configuration in the `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        crunchPngs true # <------ This option
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: PNG crunching takes a lot of time. For build time optimisation it is turned off for debug, but to save space in the final release APK it is enabled in release.